# How to place several animations in the same beamer frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations, animate

I made a handout on which are drawn parallelograms of the same area.

[image: polycop]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[np]{numprint} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed] (0,0)--(13,0);
\draw[dashed] (0,3)--(13,3);
\draw[<->,>={Latex}](.5,0)--(.5,3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{3}};
\draw[fill=green!30] (4.5,0)--(5.5,3)--(9.5,3)--(8.5,0)--cycle ;% parallelo 1
\draw[<->,>={Latex}](4.5,-.3)--(8.5,-.3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{4}};

\begin{scope}
\draw[dashed] (0,-4)--(13,-4);
\draw[dashed] (0,-1)--(13,-1);
\draw[<->,>={Latex}](.5,-4)--(.5,-1)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{3}};
\draw[fill=green!30] (8,-4)--(2,-1)--(6,-1)--(12,-4)--cycle;% parallelo 4
\draw[<->,>={Latex}](8,-4.3)--(12,-4.3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{4}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When the students have finished working, I want to project on the board the same document in the form of a slide beamer, but composed of the two following animations that will be activated at the click of the mouse.

[image: parallelogramme_un]

[image: parallelogramme_deux]

First animation:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,patterns}
\usepackage[np]{numprint}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}

\foreach \y  in {0,.2,...,3}{% découper le parallélogramme - images 1 - 16
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-6.5,-.5) rectangle (6.5,4);
        \draw[dashed] (-6.5,0)--(6.5,0);
        \draw[dashed] (-6.5,3)--(6.5,3);
        \draw[<->,>={Latex}](-6,0)--(-6,3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{3}};
        \draw[<->,>={Latex}](-2,-.3)--(2,-.3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{4}};     

        \fill[green!50](-2,0)--(-1,3)--(3,3)--(2,0)--cycle; 
        \fill[pattern=north east  lines,pattern color=blue!30](2,0)--(2,\y)--(2+\y/3,\y)--cycle;
        \draw[dashed](2,0)--(2,\y);
        \draw[dashed](2,0)--(2+\y/3,\y);
    \end{tikzpicture}
 }   

 \foreach \iangle in {2,4,...,180}{% déplacer le triangle
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[white] (-6.5,-.5) rectangle (6.5,4);
        \draw[dashed] (-6.5,0)--(6.5,0);
        \draw[dashed] (-6.5,3)--(6.5,3);
        \draw[<->,>={Latex}](-6,0)--(-6,3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{3}};
        \draw[<->,>={Latex}](-2,-.3)--(2,-.3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{4}}; 
        \fill[green!50](-2,0)--(-1,3)--(2,3)--(2,0)--cycle;
        \fill[green,opacity=.5] (\iangle:20mm and 8mm)--([shift={(0,3)}]\iangle:20mm and 8mm)--([shift={(1,3)}]\iangle:20mm and 8mm)--cycle;
        \draw[thin,dashed,pattern=north east  lines,pattern color=blue!30](2,3)--(2,0)--(3,3)--cycle;
        \draw[thin,dashed,pattern=north east  lines,pattern color=blue!30] (\iangle:20mm and 8mm)--([shift={(0,3)}]\iangle:20mm and 8mm)--([shift={(1,3)}]\iangle:20mm and 8mm)--cycle;
        \node at ([shift={(.4,1.5)}]\iangle:20mm and 8mm)[black]{\faHandPointerO};                      
     \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

Second animation:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations,arrows.meta}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{ignore}{final}{
    \state{final}{}
}

\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{start}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width={0pt},next state=middle]{
        \decoration{moveto}
    }
    \state{middle}[width={\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength*\pgfdecorationsegmentlength},next state=final]{
        \decoration{lineto}
    }
    \state{final}{\decoration{ignore}}
}

\tikzset{
    start segment/.style={decoration={start,raise=1mm},decorate, segment length=#1},
}
\tikzset{every path/.style={>={Straight Barb[]}}}
\begin{document}
\def\couleur{white}

\begin{tikzpicture}% fond écran vert - triangles 1 et 2 - image 1
    \useasboundingbox (0,3.1) rectangle (13,-.5);
    \fill[green!40](2,3) rectangle (12,0);
    \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(13,0);
    \draw[dashed] (0,3)--(13,3);
    \draw[<->](.5,0)--(.5,3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{3}};
    \draw[<->](8,-.3)--(12,-.3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{4}};   
    \fill[\couleur] (12,0)--(12,3)--(6,3)--cycle;
    \fill[\couleur] (2,0)--(2,3)--(8,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\foreach \rpos  in {.02,.04,...,1}{% inscrire le parallélogramme dans un rectangle - images 2-51
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \useasboundingbox (0,3.1) rectangle (13,-.5); 
                \fill[green!40](2,3) rectangle (12,0);
                \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(13,0);
                \draw[dashed] (0,3)--(13,3);
                \draw[<->](.5,0)--(.5,3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{3}};
                \draw[<->](8,-.3)--(12,-.3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{4}};   
                \fill[\couleur] (12,0)--(12,3)--(6,3)--cycle;
                \fill[\couleur] (2,0)--(2,3)--(8,0)--cycle;
                \draw[start segment=\rpos,blue,semithick] (2,3) -- (2,0) -- (12,0) -- (12,3) --cycle ;
            \end{tikzpicture} 
 } 

\foreach \rpos  in {.1,.2,...,3}{% colorer le triangle 2 progressivement - 30 images: 52-81
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \useasboundingbox (0,3.1) rectangle (13,-.5); 
                \fill[green!40](2,3) rectangle (12,0);
                \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(13,0);
                \draw[dashed] (0,3)--(13,3);
                \draw[<->,](.5,0)--(.5,3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{3}};
                \draw[<->](8,-.3)--(12,-.3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{4}};   
                \fill[\couleur] (12,0)--(12,3)--(6,3)--cycle;
                \fill[\couleur] (2,0)--(2,3)--(8,0)--cycle;
                \draw[blue,thin] (2,3) -- (2,0) -- (12,0) -- (12,3) --cycle ;
                \draw[blue,thin] (2,3) -- (2+2*\rpos,3-\rpos);
                \fill[pattern color=blue,pattern=north east lines](2,3)--(2+2*\rpos,3-\rpos)--(2,3-\rpos)--cycle;
            \end{tikzpicture} 
 } 

\foreach \rpos  in {.1,.2,...,3}{% colorer le triangle 1 progressivement - 30 images: 82-111
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \useasboundingbox (0,3.1) rectangle (13,-.5); 
                \fill[green!40](2,3) rectangle (12,0);
                \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(13,0);
                \draw[dashed] (0,3)--(13,3);
                \draw[<->](.5,0)--(.5,3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{3}};
                \draw[<->](8,-.3)--(12,-.3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{4}};   
                \fill[\couleur] (12,0)--(12,3)--(6,3)--cycle;
                \fill[\couleur] (2,0)--(2,3)--(8,0)--cycle;
                \draw[blue,thin] (2,3) -- (2,0) -- (12,0) -- (12,3) --cycle ;
                \draw[blue,thin] (2,3) -- (8,0);
                \fill[pattern color=blue,pattern=north east lines](2,3)--(8,0)--(2,0)--cycle;
                \draw[blue,thin] (12,0) -- (12-2*\rpos,\rpos);
                \fill[pattern color=blue,thin,pattern=north east lines](12,0)--(12,\rpos)--(12-2*\rpos,\rpos);
            \end{tikzpicture} 
 } 

\foreach \x in {11.95,11.9,...,8}{% translation du triangle 1 - 80 images: 112-191
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,3.1) rectangle (13,-.5);
        \fill[green!40](2,3) rectangle (12,0);
        \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(13,0);
        \draw[dashed] (0,3)--(13,3);
        \draw[<->](.5,0)--(.5,3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{3}};
        \draw[<->](8,-.3)--(12,-.3)node[midway,fill=white]{\numprint[cm]{4}};   
        \fill[\couleur] (2,0)--(2,3)--(8,0)--cycle;
        \draw[blue,thin] (2,3) -- (2,0) -- (12,0) -- (12,3) --cycle ;
        \draw[blue,thin] (2,3) -- (8,0);
        \fill[pattern color=blue,pattern=north east lines](2,3)--(8,0)--(2,0)--cycle;
        \draw[blue,thin,fill=white](\x,0)--(\x,3)--(\x-6,3)--cycle; 
        \fill[pattern color=blue,pattern=north east lines] (\x,0)--(\x,3)--(\x-6,3)--cycle; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }   
\end{document}
```

I tried to use the beamer's Movie command, but I couldn't.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Aire du parallélogramme}
\movie[]{}{para1.pdf}
%\includemedia[]{}{para1.pdf}

\movie[]{}{para4.pdf}
%\includemedia[]{}{para4.pdf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

- Is it possible to place two animations in the same beamer frame?
- If so, how?
- Should I change the format of animations: gif, swf, mp4, ... instead of pdf?

Comment: @marmot My goal is to be able to animate each one separately according to the progress of the students.

Comment: @marmot This is what I have always done until now, if it is impossible to do otherwise, I will do as before: only one animation per frame.

Comment: I am not saying it is impossible to have two animations. Rather, I think it should be possible, precisely in the way you describe: produce movies and embed them. However, I am not sure I myself would want to do that. Why? What will happen realistically? You will play one animation, then the second, and then both. So just define macros for each, say `\animationOne` and `\animationTwo`, on the first slide do `\animationOne{\X} \animationTwo{0}`, then `\animationOne{0} \animationTwo{\X}` and finally ``\animationOne{\X} \animationTwo{\X}` where `\X` is the variable that gets animated.

Comment: @marmot What should be the file extension of these movies? .mp4? .gif? another?

Comment: Since you seem to be French, maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20401/create-flash-animations-with-latex) could be an option? (Needless to say that I never tried it.)

Comment: @marmot Thank you very much. I'll take a closer look.

Comment: If I understood well, you want two place two animations into one frame. You want to start both at the same time while still being able to run them individually, depending on the situation. This is possible by inserting additional buttons and making use of `animate`'s JavaScript interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two animations in one frame. Buttons used for simultaneous playback control. The JavaScript interface of `animate` is used for defining the button actions.

Animations can be played back individually by clicking them directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{media9} %\mediabutton
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Two animations}
\animategraphics[label=anim1,width=\linewidth]{12}{para1}{}{}\\[1ex]
\animategraphics[label=anim2,width=\linewidth]{12}{para4}{}{}

\mediabutton[
  jsaction={anim.anim1.stopFirst();anim.anim2.stopFirst();}
]{\fbox{\faStop}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={anim.anim1.pause();anim.anim2.pause();}
]{\fbox{\faPause}}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={anim.anim1.playFwd();anim.anim2.playFwd();}
]{\fbox{\faPlay}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I must have been tired (the heat wave?) because it's quite possible to insert two animations created with the `\animategraphics` command from the `animate` package this way:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer} % Présentation générale et mise en page
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Aire du parallélogramme}
\animategraphics[]{24}{para1image}{}{}

\animategraphics[]{24}{para4image}{}{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I thank marmot and AlexG for the new tracks proposed which will allow me to conceive even prettier animations.