# Why does pgffor estimate that 0.1-0=0.100005 in a \foreach loop?

Tags: pgffor

In the manual on page 902, it says that

> Normally, when a list item ... is encountered, there should already
>   have been two list items before it, which where numbers.
>
> Examples of numbers are 1, -10, or -0.24. Let us call these numbers x and y and
>   let `d:=y−x` be their difference. Next, there should also be one number following the three dots, let us call this number `z`.
>
> In this situation, the part of the list reading `x,y,...,z` is
>   replaced by `x`, `x+d`, `x+2d`, `x+3d`,...,`x+md` where the last
>   dots are semantic dots, not syntactic dots. The value m is the largest number such that `x+md≤z` if `d is positive` or such that `x+md ≥ z` if `d is negative`.
>
> Perhaps it is best to explain this by some examples: The following  < list> have the same effects:
>
> `\foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,0.5} {\x, }` yields `0`, `0.1`, `0.20001`, `0.30002`, `0.40002`,

As here `x=0`, we deduce that `2d=0.20001` and therefore only `d=0.100005`.

**Edit:** `3d=0.30002` and therefore `d=0.10000666666...`

**Edit:** Then, in this case, `0` is subtracted from a `0.1` entry and this `0.1` entry is modified. How is this possible since nothing is subtracted from `0.1` at all?
Does this mean that subtracting `0` subtracts something from the number `0.1`?

- Is it due to binary subtraction in base 2 with `TeX`? with `pgffor`?
- is it because of the binary coding of the number 0 in `TeX?` with `pgffor`?
- How does `pgffor` calculate the increment in a foreach loop?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: very few computer programming languages can store 0.1 exactly  so such roundoff errors are not unexpected, and tex arithmetic is not particularly acurate anyway, using fixed precision dimen calculations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I understand correctly, the problem therefore comes from coding the decimal part of the real numbers and not the subtraction.

Comment: You cannot deduce from 2d=0.20001 that d=0.100005. If you do `\dimen0= 0.100005pt \showthe\dimen0`, you get `0.1pt`. If you add `\advance\dimen0 by 0.1pt \showthe\dimen0` you get `0.20001pt`. PGF uses dimen registers, which are bound to the conversions to and from binary arithmetic.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, I know that there is an approximation because `2d=0.20001` and `3d=0.30002`. It remains to be seen why not subtract nothing (subtract `0`) subtracts something!

Comment: @AndréC I can see no subtraction. Where do you see it?

Comment: @egreg, at the beginning of page 902 of the tikz manual it says this: "Normally, when a list item ... is encountered, there should already have been two list items before it, which where numbers. Examples of numbers are 1, -10, or -0.24. Let us call these numbers x and y and let d := y − x be their difference. Next, there should also be one number following the three dots, let us call this number z."

Comment: The “`d := y - x` be their difference” is meant to be read by humans. Computers have their own way of being implemented and realizing humans’ goals.

Comment: The difference is indeed `0.1-0=0.1`. But for TeX lengths, `0.1+0.1=0.20001`, as I said. Fixed point addition is different from “arithmetic” addition.

Comment: @egreg  Ok, if I understood correctly, it's not a subtraction problem, but a calculation problem with TeX's dimension registers

Comment: @AndréC Exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How does `\foreach \x in { a, b, ..., z } { <code> }` works?

Basically, PGF does

```
\start=a pt
\step=b pt
\advance\step by -\start
```

Here `a`, `b` and `z` should be decimal numbers, `\start` and `\step` are dimen registers (not the real names). Then, as the manual explains, the `<code>` is executed with `\start` having the initial value; then `\advance\start by \step` is executed and `<code>` follows. The loop goes on until `\start>z pt` (when the `<code>` will not be executed). This for `\step>0pt`, but the case `\step<0pt` is similar.

Now, how does arithmetic with dimen registers work in TeX?

A dimen register value is shown in points, but actually stored in “scaled points”, where one point is 65536 scaled points.

In your case, `\step` is set to 0.1pt, which corresponds to 6554sp. Adding again 0.1pt makes the internal value to be 13108sp. When 13108sp is converted back to points, the value is 0.20001pt.

However, `\dimen0=0.2pt` corresponds to an internal value of 13107sp, because 65536 multiplied by 2 is 131072. And `0.00001pt` is 1sp, the least nonzero TeX dimension.

With further additions, rounding errors accumulate.

Using `\foreach` with decimal values should be avoided when possible; when the values are integer, no rounding takes place.

Comment: I thought the default unit for Ti*k*Z was `cm` instead of `pt`, wasn’t it? So `0.1cm` is represented as `186479sp`, which results `(0.1+0.1)cm` as `372958sp` and so on. While `0.2cm` is supposed to be `372930sp`.

Comment: @RuixiZhang This has nothing to do with the default unit; it is how arithmetic with decimal numbers (not dimensions) is implemented.

Comment: @egreg if `\foreach` loops with decimal values should be avoided, is it better to use `\multido` or how else?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I was under the impression that drawing at `(0.1,0)` implies `(0.1cm,0cm)` being the actual implementation. How embarrassing! I’m glad I learn something new today.

Comment: @AndréC I do believe my second and third `\foreach`’s hint possible workarounds.

Comment: @RuixiZhang Indeed, it seems an interesting track. It should be tested with increments smaller than 0.1 as 0.01 or 0.02

Comment: @AndréC Smaller increments are no problems: Use `\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \y using \x/100] in {0,1,...,50}` for `0.01`, and use `\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \y using \x/50] in {0,1,...,25}` for `0.02`. The idea is to use *integer increment* so that rounding errors only occur during evaluation (the second drawing in my MWE) and thus they do not accumulate.

Comment: @RuixiZhang In this case, is it possible to modify the writing of the `pgffor` package so that `\foreach` loops always do this way?

Answer (score 12):

`0.1` in binary has infinite representation. See, for instance, [Why 0.1 Does Not Exist In Floating-Point?](https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/) So there will be rounding errors. Also, as @DavidCarlisle pointed out in the comment, TeX is good at integer arithmetic, which adds another layer of error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=16]
\foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,0.5}
    \node at (\x,0.1) {\x};
\draw (0,0.05) -- (0.5,0.05);
\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \y using \x/10] in {0,1,...,5}
    \node at (\y,0) {\y};
\draw (0,-0.05) -- (0.5,-0.05);
\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \y using \x/10] in {0,1,...,5}
    \node at (\y,-0.1) {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\y}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rounding errors]

**Added**: The binary representation of `0.1` is

> 0.00011001100110011... (0011 on repeat)

If the computer stores the above using 16 binary decimals, then it will become

> 0.0001100110011010

which converts back to `3277/32768 = 0.100006103515625`. Then you would end up with `0.20001220703125`, `0.300018310546875` and `0.4000244140625`. There is no subtraction involved here. This is just how computer stores numbers.

**Second edit**: As @egreg pointed out, the actual “floating-point arithmetic” in TeX is implemented via dimension register. So you would then be subjected to the rounding error that comes with how `pt` is converted to `sp`.

Coincidentally, since `3277/32768 = 6554/65536`, this matches *perfectly* with my illustrated conversion above: `0.1` through `0.5` are being accumulated *precisely* as `0.100006103515625`, `0.20001220703125`, `0.300018310546875`, `0.4000244140625`, and `0.500030517578125`.

Comment: Certainly `0.1` has an infinite binary writing, but here we subtract nothing from it at all since we subtract `0`. Then why does the result of the subtraction `0.1-0` modify the writing of `0.1` in binary? I edited the question.

Comment: @AndréC I don’t fully understand why you keep mentioning “subtraction”. I added some binary conversion to illustration where rounding errors came from.