# dimension to large in pgffor

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, pgffor

I have this error:
Dimension to large. }
 the code is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgffor}  
\parindent=0cm
\begin{document}
    \foreach \n in {1,...,20000}{
Hola a todos. el numero es \n   \\
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the "magical number" here is `16383`. If you loop until `16382`, it's fine. Don't ask me why, but for historical reasons TeX has that limitation. But frankly, even after a few lines the content of that document is no longer exciting. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Could you elaborate what exactly is the limitation here? If you rewrite that code with a plain `\loop \repeat` construction, you can well go beyond the 20,000 lines limit.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this qualifies for an answer. There are two facts that come into play:

1. `pgffor` works with dimensions, see e.g. [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446051/121799). This has several advantages, among them the fact that you can loop over non-integers. Drawbacks include the above observation and some inaccuracies reported e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446008/121799).
2. The maximal dimension is `16383.99999pt`, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430/121799). The loop will stop when the number exceeds `16383-1`. A precise explanation of the `-1` would require to look up the internals of `pgffor`, but I do not see a motivation for this.

So the bottom-line is that you cannot go above `16382` in the above loop.