# Animations generated in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

I just Want to ask if animations like the one in this link https://texample.net/tikz/examples/sine-and-cosine-functions-animation/, can be included in my beamer presentation or no. If not what type of animations I can include in my beamer and what I cannot

Comment: Do the answers to this question solve your problem? [How to place several animations in the same beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445535/138900)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place several animations in the same beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445535/how-to-place-several-animations-in-the-same-beamer-frame)

Comment: @AndréC: First you should flag it. second I think this feature of SE should be removed that if a comment exists with same link then don't re-comment "Does this answer your question?"